# JQuery grid with detail tables

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, jqgrid, flexigrid

I have a grid that is currently using Telerik Grids, I would like to convert this to using all Jquery with JSON. I would like to know what is the best tool to use. FlexiGrid and jQgrid are the top ones on my list although I can not find any examples with FlexiGrid having nested tables (detail tables), which is a must.

My question is, what is the best tool and is there good documentation?

I am using C# .net 4.0.

Comment: Telerik mvc grids are ok, I assume your stuck with webforms?

Comment: Benefits of things like those grids and JQuery is you can create a nested(details) table dynamically, on the fly when needed.

Comment: I did a simple demo of jqGrid and the telerik grid using a web service and then compared load times. Telerik out performed (even with more features) and in my opinion is much easier to interact with even though jqGrid might leave more customization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The demo about the usage of Master/Detail grids with jqGrid you can find [here](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). You should choose on the left tree part "Advanced" and then "Master Detail". Documentation about jqGrid you will find [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs). On the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jqgrid) and under [trirand forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393) you will find examples and answers on many questions. You can of cause ask you own question.

In my opinion jqGrid is currently the best jQuery Plugin for grids with many different features. It is active developed (see http://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid and http://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/tree/dev). Full source code in available.